# Javascript DataTable UI Libery Not getting Draw

Tags: javascript

When i add same code in jsp itself its working for me

like

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />"
    rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/demo.css" />" rel="stylesheet">

<style type="text/css" class="init">
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js">
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
    src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.dataTables.js" />">
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
    src="<c:url value="/resources/demo.js" />">
    </script>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
    /*  "ajax": '<c:url value="/resources/data/arrays.txt" />' */

            "ajax": "http://localhost:8080/SpringRestExample-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT/rest/emp/draw",
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id" },
                { "data": "name" },             
                { "data": "createdDate" }
            ]
    } );
} ); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

When i remove that ajax code and put it in js file its not working

Please give me some idea why its not getting called.

Error i got at java script level is, url got 404 error

Comment: Can You add some more debugging option to reviewers? like ajax request/response from firebug/any developer tool in browsers?

Answer (score 0):

From your question ajax is working. Problem is the URL(Since response code is 404). I think this should solve your problem.

instead of

```
"ajax": "http://localhost:8080/SpringRestExample-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT/rest/emp/draw",
```

simply use

```
"ajax": "/SpringRestExample-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT/rest/emp/draw",
```

Domain name added automatically.